# How to hide credentials in an AJAX call?

Tags: ajax, rest, api

I need to to call an API with basic auth implemented. I have a form on the frontend where a user selects some options and then the values are transmitted to an API endpoint to fetch some results.

I am planning to call the API something like this ...

```
$.ajax({
         url: WEBSERVICE_URL,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                   
            username: "admin",  // How do I HIDE this ?
            password: "mypwd",  // How do I HIDE this ?
            processData: false,
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function() {
               alert("success");
            },
            error: function() {
                   alert("ERROR");
                },
    });
```

My problem is how to **mask/hide** the login and pwd in AJAX calls ? Is it even possible ? If not, then what are the alternate solutions ? Use a PROXY ?

Comment: Is that fixed credentials the same for all clients? Hide from whom? Hide from peeking at the javascript?

Comment: Hi @Jasen Yes, credentials are same for all users. And yes, hide from people peeking at js code.

Comment: No, you cannot hide this. One option is to move the api request to your server so that the credentials are hidden from the clients, then your web server relays the api result back to the UI. But this still won't hide the credentials as it is transmitted over the wire.